# list item showing differently on ipad to any other device

Tags: ios, ipad, css

I have a list item (`ul li`) that is in my header of my site, and when it is in any browser, it works well, it works fine. But when I access the website on my ipad, the first and last link go down.

here is what I mean:

[image: any browser excluding iPad]

and this is on my iPad:

[image: using iPad browser]

Here is the code:

```
#header #personals nav ul li { 
display: inline-block; 
margin: 0; 
}
#header #personals nav ul li a { 
padding: 25px; 
margin: 0;
}
.settings { 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease; 
position: relative; 
background: url('images/settings.png') no-repeat center 15px; 
height: 20px; 
width: 50px; 
padding: 15px; 
padding-bottom: 103px; 
}
.calendar { 
background: url('images/calendar.png') no-repeat center center; 
padding: 15px; 
height: 30px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;  
width: 50px;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yvbcy/)

Comment: What about on iPhone (thinking iOS/WebKit here)? Can yiu add the markup and CSS On jsFiddle so I can look at it?

Comment: I will try jsfiddle now, but it uses images. I dont own an iphone, but it works on my mac fine, and on my blackberry

Comment: Don't worry about the images, I'll be able tonnage with just seeing markup and CSS.

Comment: @MattSmith Please see jsfiddle link in the post

Comment: Just tested on my ipad, the jsfiddle has the same result

Comment: Thanks. Looks okay on iOS7 iPhone so I'll mess around with it.

Comment: I noticed you don't have `position: relative` set on the `.calendar {}` rule but you do on the others.

Comment: Are you using a jQuery library for the calendar control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MattSmith/Yvbcy/5/)

Remove the `padding-bottom` property on the `.settings` rule and change the `15px` value on the background property to `center`.

```
.settings { 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease; 
    position: relative; 
    background: url('http://i58.tinypic.com/21o4ikl.png') no-repeat center center; 
    height: 20px; 
    width: 50px; 
    padding: 15px;
}
```